# How to automatically copy text from a group of cells to another single cell in Google Sheet

Tags: arrays, join, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, textjoin

I was wondering if anyone can help me to figure out a way to copy text from a group of cells ( in my case from D5 to D11 ) to another cell ( G6 ). I have created a google sheet for planning my dinners and when I input the ingredients for a meal ( D5 to D11 ) , I would like to have them copied to the grocery list cell ( G6 ). I know it seems very simple, but so far I have not found any good resource online.

Here below, the meal planner googles sheet. I made it available for all of you in case you want to give it a look.

[Meal Planner Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/11Nv8UcUAOnLxaLLK3ACvTWZjRzm77zQtybTYmuj0_cA/edit?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try in G6:

```
=TEXTJOIN(", "; 1; D5:D11)
```